# Power Query expand nested tables inside nested tables

Tags: powerquery

I am connecting to sharepoint list which returns a table where many columns have nested tables.
When I expand a column like that, the resulting columns have values mixed with nested tables in the same column. I.e. in one row it's a value (i.e. email title), and in another it's a [Table].

Because not all values are tables, there is no expand button anymore.
Clicking through one of these table values removes the rest of data, and there are more nested tables or records in it.

How can I expand all columns to the deepest level of nestedness? it varies between columns, too.